# 3.8.1 Production and Sandbox Environments for Data/ETL Workflows

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have been asked to upgrade from python 3.6 to 3.8.1 due to a newly found vulnerability in 3.7.2. The last few times I've tried to update my version I broke a LOT of stuff and ended up restoring from a backup before giving up. Now that I'm being forced to try again, I want to make sure I set things up right and was hoping to get some insight into the best industry-accepted method.

My main goal with this installation over my last is I want a separate sandbox and production environment so that I can test new packages or updates without breaking my workflows. Most of my workflows involve some form of reading a data source/server/making an API call, doing some transforming, and writing to a server/excel/gsheet. Everything is scheduled through a cron-like method.

Are virtual environments the correct approach here? I was thinking I would install 3.8.1 fresh then immediately create a sandbox venv before installing a single package. Then I'd convert all my workflows, get them working in this new 3.8.1 environment, then copy than venv into a new production venv. I could then do any future testing in sandbox and again copy the environment over to production any time I need updates (after much QC).

Is this a good approach? Or should one of my two environments be the main python installation and only one should be a venv? Any advice would be appreciated. If I'm heading down a bad path though I'm open to other methods. Hopefully these aren't the wrong questions for me to be asking. Although I've been using python for a few years, I have never used a venv other than creating one for the sake of trying it.

Comment: I use virtual environments for dev, test, prod; using clone for venv can be helpful.  venv provides control, switching capability and allows for minimizing (hardening) the env.

Comment: How do you go about initially setting it up though? Is "main" python installation as bare-bones as you can get? Or do you install packages there? Or is it pretty identical to your prod venv setup?

Comment: I use conda for managing environment [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Python versioning and package install can be controlled by env.

Comment: I used to use anaconda but do not like how extra stuff it adds. Also, I've run into packages that are on pip but not in the conda repository. I'm specifically trying to get this setup without conda this time around.

Comment: this is an interesting discussion [conda and pip](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)